# Não consigo passar Objetos entre controller utilizando o Brodcast e o On do AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

```
//Tenho uma injeção de dependência aqui
 PedidoController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$state','ModalService', NotificationService','PedidoService', 'BoletoService'];

// Construtor do meu controller
function PedidoController($rootScope,$state,ModalService, NotificationService, PedidoService,BoletoService)

//To passando um objeto para outro controller
function listarBoletos(pedido) { vm.boletos = pedido.boletos; $rootScope.$broadcast('BoletosSelecionados',pedido.boletos); $state.go('boleto');}

//Injection controller receptor
BoletoController.$inject = ['$scope','BoletoService'];

// Construtor Controller receptor
function BoletoController( $scope,BoletoService)

//Recepção do Objeto
$scope.$on('BoletosSelecionados',function (event, OEvent) { vm.boletos=OEvent; console.log(OEvent);
```

Comment: Tem um errinho ali na primeira linha: `'NotificationService'` não possui as aspas simples iniciais.

Comment: Já que os dois controllers possuem uma injeção do BoletoService porque você não guarda os pedidos numa variável dentro do BoletoService? Services singleton (uma instancia para a aplicação inteira) podem ser usados para compartilhar variáveis. Acredito que seja melhor em questões de performance por eliminar a necessidade de ficar monitorando eventos.

Comment: @OnoSendai eu dei uma olhada no código e a mesma está com a aspa, vlw.

Comment: @Sorack não no meu caso estou utilizando o controller inject por causa de código legado.

Comment: @arthurcláudio Quer dizer que o seu código está diferente em relação que você postou na pergunta?

Comment: obrigado por responder , cara eu sou novo no angular JS , como eu faria isso? Este codigo é legado ai já viu.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold alguma ideia de como resolvo isso?

Comment: @arthurcláudio coloca o código completo dos controllers para eu poder ajudar melhor

Comment: @FelipePaetzold só estava querendo ajudar